# How can I purge up to the completed slave binary log, minus 50?

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm using bash to purge binary logs on Master, only if the Slave has completed them.  Instead I'd like to leave a bit more logs on the server. Can you help me turn `mysql-bin.000345` into `mysql-bin.000295` (subtracting 50 from `345`)?

Here's my script:

```
# Fetch the current `Relay_Master_Log_File` from Slave
relay_master_log_file=$(ssh user@slave "mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G' | grep Relay_Master_Log_File | cut -f2- -d':' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'")

# Purge binary logs on Master up to the current `Relay_Master_Log_File`
purge_cmd="PURGE BINARY LOGS TO '$relay_master_log_file';"
ssh user@master <<EOF
mysql -e "$purge_cmd"
EOF
```

But I'd like to keep 50 (or `n`) binary logs on Master instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `mysql-bin.000345` in a variable, you could perform these steps:

1. Strip the beginning part with the trailing zeros, leaving only 345
2. Use Bash arithmetics `$((...))` to subtract `n` from 345
3. Use `printf` to format the result padded with zeros

For example:

```
oldname=mysql-bin.000345
num=$(shopt -s extglob; echo ${filename##mysql-bin.+(0)})
newname=mysql-bin.$(printf '%06d' $((num - n)))
```

Comment: The above, like so: `relay_master_log_file=$(ssh user@slave "mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G' | grep Relay_Master_Log_File | cut -f2- -d':' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'")
num=$(shopt -s extglob; echo ${relay_master_log_file##mysql-bin.+(0)})
echo $relay_master_log_file
echo $num
newname=mysql-bin.$(printf '%06s' $((num - 50)))
echo $newname` Resulted in `mysql-bin. 708` instead of `mysql-bin.000708`

Comment: @Ryan my bad, change %06s to %06d and then it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can get it in your first command itself using `awk` and **as a bonus** skip use of `grep`, `cut` and `sed`.

```
# Fetch the current `Relay_Master_Log_File` from Slave
relay_master_log_file=$(ssh user@slave "mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G' |
awk -F':[[:blank:]]*' '$1~/Relay_Master_Log_File/{split($2, a, /\./); printf "%s.%06d", a[1], a[2]-50}'
)
```

---

Based on comments below use:

```
ssh user@slave <<-'EOF'
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G' |
awk -F':[[:blank:]]*' '$1~/Relay_Master_Log_File/{split($2, a, /\./);
     printf "%s.%06d\n", a[1], a[2]-50}'
EOF
```

Comment: I like this approach, but it errors when I try to run it all at once: `# Fetch Current Log, minus 50:
 ssh user@slave <<EOF
 mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G' | awk -F':[[:blank:]]*' '$1~/Relay_Master_Log_File/{split($2, a, /\./); printf "%s.%06d", a[1], a[2]-50}'
 EOF

 # Result:
 awk: cmd. line:1: ~/Relay_Master_Log_File/{split(, a, /\./); printf "%s.%06d", a[1], a[2]-50}
 awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
 awk: cmd. line:1: ~/Relay_Master_Log_File/{split(, a, /\./); printf "%s.%06d", a[1], a[2]-50}
 awk: cmd. line:1:                                ^ syntax error`

Comment: I have `$1` before `~/Relay_Master_Log_File/` in awk command. Use **`ssh user@slave <<'EOF'`** to avoid `$1` being expanded.

Comment: Yes and it also cuts down multiple pipelines commands like `grep+cut+sed` by getting desired filename directly.